# Creating SQL Windows login for External Domain

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, windows-authentication, database-schema, database-project

**Problem**

Is it somehow possible to create a Windows Authentication login for a SQL database without performing a check for the user at creation time?

**Example**

Consider `ServerA` that exists in our `DomainA`, and `ServerB` that exists in the customer's `DomainB`. Being separate companies, `DomainA` and `DomainB` never share resources. But, if we backup from `ServerB` and restore to `ServerA`, we are able to see the existing SQL logins for users from `DomainB`, and even modify and code against these logins. This is good, because we are able to develop the database schema on ServerA and then publish to ServerB.

But, if I want to add a new user for this database, and am working on `ServerA` in `DomainA`, the following command produces an error:

```
CREATE USER [DomainB\User];
Windows NT user or group 'DomainB\User' not found. Check the name again. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15401)
```

This is bad, because we're no longer able to develop on ServerA using the same schema as ServerB.

**Backstory**

I'm attempting to bring our database-driven application's database schema into source control using a Visual Studio 2010 Database Project. It's important to me to make this work well enough to convince the boss not to continue using 60-GB database backups in a zip file as a means of 'Version Control' (especially since this is just for schema, and not a backup routine). VS2010 DB Projects use scripting to create/modify databases, and so they can't create WinNT users for an unknown domain. In order to get the boss's buy-off, we're going to have to be able to match the capabilities of restoring a backup, and that means being able to re-create users for domains that we don't have access to.

Using SQL Server 2008 in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Note - DBProjects are best suited to managing and versioning your SCHEMA, not your data.

If you want to keep rolling backups of your SQL databases as a whole, then I'd recommend a decent backup strategy.

If you want to better manage your databases' evolving schemas, then using DBProjects may well be your best bet.

FWIW, if you reverse-engineer a DB into a DBProj, you could then run a script to replace DomainB\known-user with DomainA\known-user prior to deploying within DomainA, no?

Comment: I have updated my question a bit to reflect a possible point of confusion. The data does not need to be maintained. Also, we're developing on ServerA with the intent to deploy on ServerB. Still, your suggestion of duplicating the userbase from DomainB to DomainA and using search/replace for the scripts is worth mentioning as a workaround. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, because SQL needs to know the windows SID (ugly GUID) of the user at the time it's created.

Note that you can, however create a SQL or Windows User with the same name and password as your remote SQL, Machine, or Domain user, and it will be able to log in.

Comment: Create a windows user with the same name? This happens to not be the case. This may work for `SQL logins`, but my question is based around `Windows logins`. In order to create a Windows login, I must use the form `Domain\Username`. So I can't simply create a Windows login for `User`. Also, in order to create a login `DomainB\User`, the computer that I'm using needs to be able to access `DomainB` to verify that `User` exists. Since I'm not connected to `DomainB`, my computer cannot run this check, and the `Add Login` fails.

Comment: Right. But you can create a SQL user for `Username` that matches the one for the domain user account. As long as the password for the SQL login matches the domain user, it will authenticate successfully.